# Contact from, PHP doesn't return string to AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, forms, cross-domain, contacts

I have AJAX contact form on my hosting server and mail.php file on different domain (another hosting). I am trying to validate a form with jQuery and send email using AJAX, but when I call php file, it sends email to mail email box, but doesn't return a 'success' message. Instead I get "an empty string".

I have in js

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: options.url,
    data: {subject:options.subject, name:$('#name').val(), email:$('#email').val(), message:$('#message').val()},
    success: function(data){
       if( data == 'success') {
           $('#callback').append(options.recievedMsg);
       } else {
           $('#callback').append(options.notRecievedMsg);
       }
    });
```

And php looks like this

```
    <?php
    define( "RECIPIENT_NAME", "John Smith" );
    define( "RECIPIENT_EMAIL", "my.email@mail.com" );
    define( "EMAIL_SUBJECT", "Visitor Message" );

    $senderName = stripcslashes($_POST['name']);
    $senderEmail = stripcslashes($_POST['email']);
    $message = stripcslashes($_POST['message']);

    if ( $senderName && $senderEmail && $message ) {
        $recipient = RECIPIENT_NAME . " <" . RECIPIENT_EMAIL . ">";
        $headers = "From: " . $senderName . " <" . $senderEmail . ">";
        $success = mail( $recipient, EMAIL_SUBJECT, $message, $headers );
    };

    echo 'success';

    ?>
```

When I check in console 'data' value it says (an empty string) and in ajax if function I always get false and notReceived message.

How can I make php file to return 'success' that if(data == 'success') state would be true? Am I missing sometehing here?

Comment: what is this  url: options.url,? is it correct url. pls give tha value of  " options.url ",

Comment: Search for "CORS" as you may need to add this to the server and jQuet call. Also get the result sent back as "JSONP" not plain text. Or as a last option, set up a "proxy" (can you put a PHP script on your hosting server?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send an AJAX request to another domain because of the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).